# Не работает justify-content center в IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Все хорошо отображается в Google Chrome, но в IE11 все выглядит иначе:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header .box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы центровка на [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex) заработала в IE11 нужно родителю задать свойство `flex-direction` со значением `row` или `column`.

Абстрактный пример:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Center (X-Axis)</p>
```

На примере Вашего кода:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header .box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_box">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: но, если элементов слишком много центрирование перестает работать в ie, как это пофиксить? крайний элемент вствет у левого края, а не уходит за него